# Cython Memoryviews -- Seg Fault on Large Arrays?

Tags: python, cython

Seeing strange behavior for even very small simple integer arrays.

```
%%cython
import numpy as np
cimport cython
cimport numpy as np

def hi():
    DEF MAX = 10000000
    cdef int a[MAX],i
    cdef int[:] a_mv = a
```

This crashes, but views into smaller views perform mine. This isn't obvious a memory issue as there's ample RAM for 10 million ints...

Comment: There's ample RAM, but not ample stack space.

Comment: You're creating a big C array on the stack, it will fail, this has nothing to do with Cython.

Comment: Very very true. This was a stupid question. ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Kevin mentions in his comment, the problem is not the RAM, but the stack. You are allocating an array of 10 million elements *on the stack*, when you should really allocate it *on the heap*, using `malloc` et friends. Even in C this produces a Segmentation Fault:

```
 /* bigarray.c */
int main(void) {
    int array[10000000];
    array[5000000] = 1;   /* Force linux to allocate memory.*/
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -O0 bigarray.c   #-O0 to prevent optimizations by the compiler
$ ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

While:

```
/* bigarray2.c */
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *array;
    array = malloc(10000000 * sizeof(int));
    array[5000000] = 1;
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -O0 bigarray2.c
$ ./a.out 
$ echo $?
0
```